# Looking for proper code structure for multiple associated array with conditionals

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative

I am having an issue getting foreach loops to work correctly.  After breaking out of a foreach after a match of a value, it doesn't seem to iterate through the rest of the array.

If I take the elseif block out the inner if works as expected.  With the elseif and with or without break 2, the value of $ipaddr doesn't change.

Does the foreach loops being inside a while loop cause the foreach loops to reset or start over?

I tried using break and continue but they don't seem to help.

```
while ( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($sqlquery, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
     echo "<tr><td>"
     foreach ($query['result']['nat']['rules'] as $value) {
          foreach ($value as $data) {
               $daddr = substr($data['destination']['member'], 4);
               $ipaddr = str_replace("host_","",$data['destination-translation']['translated-address']);
               if ( ( array_key_exists('destination-translation', $data))) {
                    if ($daddr == $row['VIP/NAT'])  {
                         echo "<td>" . $daddr . "</td><td>" . $ipaddr . "</td><td>" . "STATIC" . "</td></td>";
                    }
                    else {
                          echo "<td> </td><td>" . $ipaddr . "</td><td> </td></tr>";
                          break 2;
                    }
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

Comment: what about if you switch the outer `while` for a `foreach`? can you add a better example of the input/output? I am not seeing a why they should exit unless it has not more data to iterate over

Comment: Notice that you `elseif` can be replace with just `else`

Comment: Right.  I forgot to clean that up.  I don't understand why the inner if works but the else doesn't.

Comment: If I break out of the foreach loops, wouldn't the next pass of the while loop start the foreach from the top?